# How do I search Google BY html-tags?

Tags: search, tags, advanced-search

How do I search Google (or another indexing site) by HTML tags? The keywords I'm looking for are embedded in the title tags of a domain. Anyone know?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using a web service. [Webapps SE](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) would be an appropriate place for this question.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is:

> allintitle

e.g. allintitle : Star Wars - Will return all pages with 'Star Wars' in the title.

The best way of finding these search types is to just head over to the google advanced search page http://www.google.com/advanced_search